# Return code of the command before the pipe

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop, pipe, rpm

I'm trying to verify rpms, assign some variables in a while loop and do some more processing inside the loop.

```
    while read fstatus fname rc
    do
       echo "RC : ${lrc}" 
    done < <(rpm --verify apache2 | awk -vrc=$? '{printf "%s %s %s", $1, $NF, rc}')
```

There are a few things in the loop that I want to do only if my return code is no 0 (So only if the rpm verification failed).
I don't know how to get the rpm --verify return code inside the loop. The *$?* or *PIPESTATUS* assignment doesn't work. 
I guess my questions is, would the command after the pipe (awk in my case) would know the return code of the command right before the pipe (rpm --verify in this case).

Comment: No, awk doesn't get the return code, since it runs before `rpm` finishes. The return code is only returned to the calling process, which is the shell.

Comment: From http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution: _It is not possible to obtain the exit code of a process substitution command, from the shell that created the process substitution_

Comment: I think you'll have to write `rpm`'s output to a temp file to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rpm --verify apache2 > tempfile && awk -vrc=$? '{printf "%s %s %s", $1, $NF, rc}' tempfile
```

This way the awk will be executed only if rpm --verify succeeded. If it fails, the awk will not run and you will get it's status in the $?.

Comment: Works for me. Since I'm running the loop to do some post processing on the rpms which fail verification, I just changed the && to ||. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (passing the value of RC as a string):

```
while read fstatus fname rc
do
  echo "RC : ${lrc}" 
done < <( { v=$(rpm --verify apache2); printf "%s\n" "$v $?" ;} | awk '{printf "%s %s %s\n", $1, $(NF-1), $NF}')
```

Note that the `\n` in the awk printf is required to properly feed the read loop.

---edit----
Learned that RC needs to be printed on every line. Perhaps this would then be more fitting:

```
done < <( v=$(rpm --verify apache2) ; awk -v rc=$? '{printf "%s %s %s\n", $1, $NF, rc}' <<< "$v" )
```

-- 
Just saw the other solution. I guess the only difference is writing to a file or a variable..

Comment: Doesn't work. since the return code is only printed after all the lines are printed. For the while loop to work, it needs to be printed at the end of each line.

`S.5....T c /etc/apache2/default-server.conf
S.5....T c /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
S.5....T c /etc/apache2/listen.conf
S.5....T c /etc/apache2/mod_log_config.conf
S.5....T c /etc/apache2/mod_mime-defaults.conf
S.5....T /etc/apache2/server-tuning.conf 1`